# Questions about instrument care and repair

Tags: discussion, scope, topics, questions

Should questions regarding the care and repair of our instruments be considered on topic here? Why? Why not?

Could that be extended to questions about *making* musical instruments?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Care and repair should definitely be on-topic.  It's closely related to Musical Performance and drawing a line between them would not be useful.

I'm not as sure about instrument construction.  While there's certainly a large overlap, I would assume the majority of relevant questions are irrelevant to the average musician.  That said, I would have no problem with this site being host to them unless the [Musical Instrument Construction, Maintenance, and Repair](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21054/musical-instrument-construction-maintenance-and-repair) proposal takes off.  If it does we would presumably migrate our own care & repair questions there as well.

Comment: I too think it's fair game. It's something we fielded on Guitars.SE pretty frequently.

Comment: Probably most home instrument construction is for wooden instruments (let's face it, it's going to be 99% guitars), and therefore there's overlap with WoodWorking.SE.