# What is the tune that goes..

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions of the form "What are the notes to this (popular refrain)?" ok or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do questions about reverse engineering compositions fit on this site?](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/35/do-questions-about-reverse-engineering-compositions-fit-on-this-site)

Comment: I recommend we group this kind of questions in the form of answers to the FAQ proposal (see featured meta question: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-should-our-faq-contain )

Comment: This can be answered by Googling for a score usually, so I say no, it's not right for this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't think they're in the spirit of the site.

It would be a slippery slope, especially considering copyright laws, etc.

Comment: Agreed.  As per the answers to the possible-duplicate, we would prefer to help people be able to figure it out themselves.  We are specifically not a repository for music.